# How to send a notification alert when a process is killed by the OOM killer?

Tags: linux, notifications, out-of-memory

So every now and then (once in a month or two) one of our processes, running a critical piece of code that we don't want to touch, is being killed by the Out Of Memory killer.  It says so in `/var/log/messages`.

We are going to address the *cause* separately.  I want to monitor and address the *effects* right now.  I want us (the sysops) to be sent a notification whenever this happens, so that we can wait for an hour or so for the traffic on the cluster to die down a bit and restart the task that was killed.

How do I arrange for such a notification to happen?

I think we run Red Hat Linux on our boxes if it matters.

Comment: I suggest running `cat /etc/*-release | mail <receiver>` every once in a while so you guys at least know what OS is running the "critical piece of code"...

Comment: This is a abuse of that closure reason.  Clearly, a question about _the OOM killer_ and _logs in `/var/log/messages`_ is talking about a Unix or Linux system.

Comment: I agree. I think it's a very bad question and the problem *should* be solved by the root of it and therefore might be better off on stack overflow, but in the context of this specific question it does fit on the unix&linux SE imo.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad question. I just noticed a service had been killed two days ago on one of our servers. I wish I had been notified. So while the root issue needs to be addressed, if there was a simple way to get notifications on OOM frags (just like we get mails on cron issues, apt updates, etc.), I'd activate this on our servers.